# Specify percentage instead of time to ffmpeg

Tags: image, video, image-processing, ffmpeg, thumbnails

To get a thumbnail from an image halfway through the video I can do `ffmpeg -ss 100 -i /tmp/video.mp4 -frames:v 1 -s 200x100 image.jpg`. By using `-ss 100` it gets a thumbnail at `100` seconds (which would be halfway through the video assuming the video is `200` seconds long).

But if I don't know the exact length of the video, in my application code I would need to use something like `ffprobe` to first determine the length of the video, and then divide it by 2 to get the thumbnail time.

Is there a way to get ffmpeg to get the thumbnail at the percentage of the video you want? So instead of specifying `-ss 100`, something like `-ss 50%` or `-ss 20%` to get a thumbnail from halfway or 20% into the file?

I know I can do this through application code, but it would be more efficient if there's a way for ffmpeg to handle this itself.

Comment: have you found it yet ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because , as the ffmpeg tag states: **Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic. Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on https://superuser.com/ or https://video.stackexchange.com/**. Please delete this.

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty but:

```bash
ffmpeg -y -i logo-13748357.mp4 -vf "select=gte(n\,$(shuf -i 1-$(ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=nb_frames -of default=nokey=1:noprint_wrappers=1 logo-13748357.mp4)  -n 1))" -vframes 1 out_img.png
```

The above command is an example of a one liner that grabs the number of frames in a video and passes that to the "shuf" command https://linux.die.net/man/1/shuf which randomly selects a number in the range of frames and the result of that is passed to ffmpeg.

So the above is able to randomly select a frame from a video with just one line.

You might be able to adapt this approach to your specific goal.  Presuming of course it still matters seven years down the track.